# Django Vue.js PasswordResetView posted with Axios gets Error 403 Forbidden CSRF Token

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a custom Email Restore page in the frontend with Vue.js. There, I am trying to send input with an email with Axios through /api/v1/accounts/password_reset/, so basically I am trying to use the original ResetPasswordView and instead of using its template, I am using it as an endpoint. When I submit the value, the console returns Error 403 Forbidden CSRF Token, like below. What can be done to avoid it?

```js
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/v1/accounts/password_reset/
[07/Sep/2021 16:32:55] "POST /api/v1/accounts/password_reset/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2864
/Users/IvanStepanchuk/Desktop/web-project/web-backend/core/settings.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

This is my ResetPassword.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div id="login">
        <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center" id="home__screen">
            <div class="col-sm col-lg-4 text-center align-self-center decorator__spacing">
                <div class="card bg-white p-4">
                    <h1 class="fs-3 pb-3">Recover your account</h1>
                    <form @submit.prevent="passwordReset">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" v-model="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email con el cual se ha registrado">
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-primary d-flex flex-column" role="alert" v-if="errors.length">
                            <span v-for="error in errors" v-bind:key="error">{{error}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Enviar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'ResetPassword',
  data() {
      return {
          email: '',
          errors: []
      }
  },
  components: {
    
  },
  mounted() {
      document.title = 'Company | Recover Account'
  },
  methods: {
        passwordReset() {
            this.errors = []
            if (this.email === '') {
                this.errors.push('Email field is empty')
            }

            const passwordResetForm = {
                email: this.email
            }
            axios
                .post("/api/v1/accounts/password_reset/", passwordResetForm)
                .then(response => {
                    this.$router.push('/login')
                    return response
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errors.push('Something is not working well')
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }

  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Or what would be the best way to use custom Vue.js views to manage password reset functionality (so it doesn't use Django templates)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve that by creating custom Views.py methods and Classes, you can see the solution here: [Django Rest Framework + Serializers + Vue.js, Reset Password Functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049040/django-rest-framework-serializers-vue-js-reset-password-functionality)

- This is not a duplicate. It is a similar topic with a different approach that worked well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `passwordResetForm` does not have csrf_token in it. Well it is just an object with email in it. Django does not allow this by default for security reasons. (for details see: [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/) about CSRF)

You can get the csrf token from the page with this code:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

And then pass the csrftoken in the headers of your `ajax.post()`

Comment: Awesome, this will work nicely. Thank you! Also, I am working on a workaround, that will allow change passwords and more via custom Vue.js views. Will share the code later.

Comment: @IvanStepanchuk, any chance you could share the code?

Comment: Hi @finite_diffidence, the solution for that problem can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049040/django-rest-framework-serializers-vue-js-reset-password-functionality. That approach above didn't work for me so I had to make it in a different manner, like a workaround.